# Theano converting from TensorType col to TensorType matrix

Tags: casting, theano, tensor

I'm getting an error due to checks inside Theano's scan function that check if the same type of variable is used multiple places. This function does not allow a `(N, 1)` of the col TensorType to be exchanged with a `(N, 1)` matrix (see error below).

How do I cast/convert a `(N, 1)` Tensor of the `col` TensorType to the `matrix` TensorType?

```
TypeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', forall_inplace,cpu,scan_fn}(TensorConstant{20}, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0,2}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, TensorConstant{20}, condpred_1_W_ih, condpred_1_W_ho, embedding_1_W, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0, AdvancedIncSubtensor{inplace=False, set_instead_of_inc=True}.0), '\n', "Inconsistency in the inner graph of scan 'scan_fn' : an input and an output are associated with the same recurrent state and should have the same type but have type 'TensorType(int32, matrix)' and 'TensorType(int32, col)' respectively.")
```

Comment: when you declare the variables, either make both of them `col` or `matrix`?

Comment: I'm not declaring either of them specifically as either `col` or `matrix`. For instance, this is my initialization of one of them: `K.zeros((self.batch_size, 1), dtype='int32')`

Comment: It seems that one of them is being converted implicitly within the Theano `step` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `theano.tensor.patternbroadcast`.

If you see [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#all-fully-typed-constructors), the shape of `fmatrix` is `(?, ?)` and that of `fcol` is `(?, 1)`. The meaning of `?` is that dimension can take any value. So shape is not a good differentiator between `fmatrix` and `fcol`. Now, see in the broadcastable column. Last dimension of `fmatrix` is not broadcastable while that of `fcol` is. So the following code should convert between these types.

Let us convert a matrix to a col and then vice-versa.

```
from theano import tensor as T

x = T.fmatrix('x')
x_to_col = T.patternbroadcast(x, (False, True))
x.type
x_to_col.type

y = T.fcol('y')
y_to_matrix = T.patternbroadcast(y, (False, False))
y.type
y_to_matrix.type
```

Run the above commands in a console to see that the data types have indeed changed. So you either change your `fmatrix` variable or your `fcol` one.

Comment: Ignore my previous (now deleted) comments. It works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I thought so. I found the error message in the Theano source code :). I thought maybe you were passing `x` in a wrong manner.

Comment: Do you have a good reference, where I can read about the intuition behind why broadcastable affects the interpretation of a tensor as being either a `col` or a `matrix`? :) I can't find a nice explanation on the Theano site.